# Merging "add" form in Django Admin from 2 or more Models (connected with one-to-one relationship)

Tags: python, django

I have a Django's default `UserCreationForm` to add a new user via Admin app. I want to add new fields from another custom model called `UserProfile`. The `UserProfile` has a One-to-One relationship with Django's `User` model. The additional fields which `UserProfile` model has are `phone number`, `company name` etc.

Is there a way where I can merge `UserProfile` form with Django's default `User` form while creation of the new user from Admin panel?

I looked at Django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) on Inline forms but seems their require foreign key relationship.

`Django 2.1`

Comment: It might take some work but you can extend `AbstractUser`. If you decide to go this route you will also need to make a custom UserCreationForm. See: [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model). Although there are probably simpler ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at Custom User Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `Profile` with extra field `phone_number`. Like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=24)
```

You can follow following steps to add extra fields in `UserCreationForm` in Admin.

**1. Create custom `UserCreationForm`**

Inherit from `UserCreationForm` and Add extra fields and functionality.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from account.models import Profile

class UserWithProfileCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=32)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=True)
        profile = Profile(user=instance, phone_number=self.cleaned_data['phone_number'])
        profile.save()
        return instance
```

**2. Unregister (already registered) `User` model and register again with custom form and fields**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# unregister first
admin.site.unregister(User)


@admin.register(User)
class UserWithProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserWithProfileCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            # add any custom fields here
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'phone_number'),
        }),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.
First, you can create a custom `User` model from `AbstractBase`

```
# models.py
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile)
```

And then update your admin view.

```
#admin.py

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserProfileInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Second, you can simply add the `OneToOneField(User)` in your `UserProfile` model, and follow the similar method to update the admin view.